# Geolocation for a flash ad

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

How would I find the geolocation of a viewer (city and state) and then translate that into something I can use for flash?

Comment: Who will be serving the ads? (Doubleclick / MediaMind / self-served).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to provide geolocation data to a flash ad, the best source is to get that data from your ad vendor. Ads have a special case for high-avaiablity and high-speed servers. Implementing this is non-trivial, and if your add is slow-performaing, publishers will complain and your campaign will get dropped.

Here is a page listing the leading ad media vendors. They will be able to work with you on your ad buy to provide GEOIP for your ad unit.
http://advertising.microsoft.com/asia/ForAdvertisers/default.aspx?pageid=183

(and I'm sorry they don't link directly to the ad vendor sites, but this was the best list i could find. Each company comes up as first if you google their name.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service like http://www.ip2location.com/ to get the users location based on their IP address when the page loads, and then translate the lat/lng coordinates into flash vars and pass those into your .swf file.  The nice thing about using a service like this is that you don't have to maintain an ip lookup db yourself.